# Table borders strange behavior

Tags: html, css

I have template for e-mail list, in html + css.

http://tsiskreli.highlander.ge/next.html

Here it is. There is no php, javascript, only html and css everything in this file.
In all browsers (chrome, firefox, explorer) I see it fine, top text is in right place and table looks fine.
My costumer sees it so:
http://s1.postimg.org/7c4iffav3/image004.jpg

I see it so even with 300% zoom:

http://s21.postimg.org/t1jltp0fb/Screenshot_12.jpg

Why my costumer sees this empty space in at the border and why reservation goes down for him?

Comment: Please don't link to external content, instead include the relevant code/images in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you ask the CSS to do so. Try to view it under 480px screen and you will get the some result as your customer. After inspecting your CSS i found this :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    td[class=mcnImageCardLeftImageContent],td[class=mcnImageCardRightImageContent]{
        padding-right:18px !important; /* This is it */
        padding-left:18px !important;  /* This is it */
        padding-bottom:0 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This media query is causing the padding :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    td[class=mcnTextContent] {    
        padding-right: 18px !important;
        padding-left: 18px !important;
    }
}
```

#### Remarks :

- Don't duplicate the media query for each property: you can group them all inside one.
- Use `!important` with caution.
- [Don't use table for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold), and especially not like this: your html structure is a mess.
- Consider adding the relevant code in your question by the way.